# Version Compatibility of IBM Db2 database

Tags: db2, ibm-integration-bus

We have 2 IIB DB2 servers,.
What is the latest DB2 version we can upgrade to be compliant with the IBM IIB version.

The two servers with the DB2 database for IIB need to be upgraded ( currently windows 2012 R2 ) , the current DB2 version can’t be upgraded to Windows 2016 or Windows 2019 , Is there a possibility without changing IIB version if we can upgrade DB2 database?

Existing DB2 version 10.5
Current Windows 2012 R2 standard.
Current IIB version 10.0.0.12.